# Steppers drivers that take 3.3V (TTL) inputs

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am currently using a stepper driver from omc-stepper online. The PUL and DIR inputs work fine with 3.3V logic but not the ENA input.

Are there any stepper drivers that take 3.3V inputs?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet you can share for what you are using now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider Pololu A4988 Stepper Motor Driver Carrier instead. https://www.pololu.com/product/1182/specs
The minimum logic voltage of this stepper motor driver is 3 V. You can give 3.3V to the Enable pin with no issues.